# How to add seperate overflow menus for each activity in android

Tags: android, android-studio, menu

In my android project there are about 10 activities up to now, I want these activities to have separate overflow menus(one overflow menu for each activity with different items in it), is it possible? if it is possible then can any one tell me how to create them. I using the Android Studio as my IDE.
Here are some of my source codes

```
menu_main.xml

<menu xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools" tools:context=".MainActivity">
    <group android:checkableBehavior="single">
        <!--only one item can be seleted-->

        <item
            android:id="@+id/itemBlue"
            android:orderInCategory="1"
            android:title="@string/blueText"
            app:showAsAction="never" />

        <item
            android:id="@+id/itemRed"
            android:orderInCategory="2"
            android:title="@string/redText"
            app:showAsAction="never"
            />

        <item
            android:id="@+id/itemGreen"
            android:title="@string/greenText"
            app:showAsAction="never"
            android:orderInCategory="3"
            />


    </group>


</menu>
```

here is one activity, which is HomeScreen.java

```
import android.content.Intent;
import android.graphics.Color;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v7.app.ActionBarActivity;
import android.view.MenuItem;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.ImageButton;
import android.widget.RelativeLayout;

public class HomeScreen extends ActionBarActivity implements View.OnClickListener {
    private ImageButton ibLogin,ibSeeTimeTable;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_home_screen);

        ibLogin=(ImageButton)findViewById(R.id.ibLogin);
        ibSeeTimeTable=(ImageButton)findViewById(R.id.ibSeeTimeTable);

        ibLogin.setOnClickListener(this);
        ibSeeTimeTable.setOnClickListener(this);


    }

    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        switch (v.getId()){
            case R.id.ibLogin:
                startActivity(new Intent(this,MainActivity.class));

                break;

            case R.id.ibSeeTimeTable:
                startActivity(new Intent(this,SelectTimeTable.class));
                finish();
                break;
        }

    }
@Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.menu_main, menu);
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    // this method is called when an item is being selected from overflow menu
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        // Handle action bar item clicks here. The action bar will
        // automatically handle clicks on the Home/Up button, so long
        // as you specify a parent activity in AndroidManifest.xml.

        //first we have to make an object of the RelativeLayout
        RelativeLayout relativeLayout = (RelativeLayout) findViewById(R.id.mainMenu);

        switch (item.getItemId()) {
            case R.id.itemBlue:
                if (item.isChecked()) {
                    //if it is already checked
                    item.setChecked(false);
                } else {
                    item.setChecked(true);
                }


                relativeLayout.setBackgroundColor(Color.BLUE);
                return true;

            case R.id.itemGreen:
                if (item.isChecked()) {
                    item.setChecked(false);

                } else {
                    item.setChecked(true);

                }
                relativeLayout.setBackgroundColor(Color.GREEN);
                return true;

            case R.id.itemRed:
                if (item.isChecked()) {
                    item.setChecked(false);

                } else {
                    item.setChecked(true);
                }
                relativeLayout.setBackgroundColor(Color.RED);

                return true;
            // this indicate that the event is handled

            default:
                return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
            //if any event doesnot catch it, then this default works

        }
        //noinspection SimplifiableIfStatement

    }
}
```

I have more than 10 other activites, how do I add seperate overflow methods for them

Comment: @Mukesh Rana I have added some of the code

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should override the onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) method in each activity and specify a menu xml resource relevant to that activity. Example:

In app/res/menu create an xml for each activity:
    menu_activity1.xml
    menu_activity2.xml
    menu_activity3.xml

Then in each activity:

```
@Override
public boolean onCreateoptionsMenu(Menu menu){
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.menu_activity1, menu);
    return true;
}
```

Then, of course, override the onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) to respond appropriately.

On a separate note: fragments, dude, fragments!

Comment: Can you explain me how to do it through fragments, I know a little bit of fragments, as I watched this tutorial [link](https://www.google.com/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=1&cad=rja&uact=8&ved=0ahUKEwjx86acmtLKAhXJvhQKHWAQAUwQtwIIHTAA&url=https%3A%2F%2Fwww.youtube.com%2Fwatch%3Fv%3DdQ6uc__qP-g&usg=AFQjCNG2d5LNgfAG0wO34-wR21QMXAS1yg&sig2=Xx3FCJVgBpQYg2ngAR7CXw), if you can please guide me to a resource material

Comment: Android will keep every one of your activities alive in memory while your app is running in case you want to use them again, which is inefficient for large numbers of activities. A better design would be to have a single activity for your app and then change the views by adding, removing, and replacing fragments instead of changing activities. [Here](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/android/android_fragments.htm) may be helpful. You can set a container fragment and use it to hold other fragments and consider the container to be like an activity, adding it to the backStack for navigation for ex.